# Hibernate @OneToMany(mappedBy="...") relation not being cached

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a following class called Article (simplified):

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Article")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
class Article {
    // .....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author.article")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    Set<ArticleAuthorInformation> authors;
}
```

The authors field creates a relation to the `User` class. The reason why there is `ArticleAuthorInformation` instead of User is that I need extra information for this relation (the royalty paid for the article).

This is what it looks like:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Cacheable
public class ArticleAuthorInformation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    ArticleAuthor author;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    int royalty;
}
```

ArticleAuthor is a combined primary key as follows:

```
@Embeddable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Cacheable
public class ArticleAuthor implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Article article;
    // .....
}
```

I've added tonnes of @Cache annotations everywhere, but whenever I access the `authors` Set in Article, the following query is always made by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select articleaut0_.article_id as article2_2_0_, articleaut0_.user_login as user3_2_0_, articleaut0_.royalty as royalty2_0_ from ArticleAuthorInformation articleaut0_ where articleaut0_.article_id=? and articleaut0_.user_login=?
```

If you take a look at the query, it doesn't make any sense at all! It is basically asking only for the `royalty` field (as it apparently knows the value of other fields), which I'm not accessing anywhere in the code. I've even marked the `royalty` field as lazy, but Hibernate still keeps querying for it.

Removing the `royalty` field makes the query go away, but that's not a solution, I will need the field to exist...

Comment: Why are you making an int field lazy loaded?

Comment: As I mentioned in the text, I'm trying to prevent that query from being made. It's not doing anything, actually.

Comment: Which version of orm do you use ?